# how to use like query in hql when in list values?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hql

I using spring mvc.
This is my old code it perfects correctly.

```
public List<Details> filter(String search) {
    TypedQuery<Details> query = em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT um FROM Details um INNER JOIN um.admin ad WHERE um.name like :search and ad.status =:status", Details.class );
    String searchkey = search;
    String status = "True";
    query.setParameter("search", searchkey + '%');
    query.setParameter("status", status);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

In that the Details class containing the name as string.

```
public class Details implements Serializable {
@Column(name="name")
private String name;
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name ="id")
private List<Email> email= new ArrayList<Email>();
 }
```

Like that I want use search as email, in like instead of name I want to use email. Now I try below code, but it shows error.

```
public List<Details> filterEmail(String search) {
    System.out.println("Email filtering query..");
    TypedQuery<Details> query = em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT um FROM Details um INNER JOIN um.admin ad WHERE elements(um.email) like :search and ad.status =:status", Details.class );
    String status = "True";
    query.setParameter("search",'%' +search+ '%');
    query.setParameter("status", status);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

How can I use that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not searching on the mail property of your Email Object like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT um FROM Details um 
INNER JOIN um.admin ad 
WHERE ad.mailproperty like :search and ad.status =:status
```